# Unable to load POST request Body in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, http-post, wkwebview

I'm trying to access POST request HTTP body using WKWebView.

I'm getting following error msg. I have added my code sample below

// load request
func loadWkWebview() {

```
    if var postRequest = postURLRequest {
        wkWebview.load(postRequest)
    }
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(wkWebview)

    wkWebview.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits.staticText
    wkWebview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

}

// WKWebView Delegate
extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    debugPrint("Error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
    hideLoader()
    loadWkWebview() // re-calling func
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if self.wkWebview.isLoading {
        showLoader()
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.hideLoader()
        print(error.localizedDescription) // I'm getting error here
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.hideLoader()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    // url handeling done here
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}

 func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation, withError error: NSError) 
{
     if error.code == Error_Request_Cancelled 
     {
         return
     }

    self.loadingView.hide()
    if webView.isLoading
    {
        AppUtility.addDelay(forTimeInterval: 2)
       {
            self.noNetworkView.isHidden = false
            self.setUpErrorScreenUI()
        }
    }
}
```

> Error-> "The URL can’t be shown"

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code snippet?

Comment: Thanks, but it would be easier to read if you edit your question and paste your code there, with proper formatting. Also please specify the URL you are trying to load.

Comment: @GregdeJ Due to privacy reasons, I can't share the URL.

Comment: Your code is mostly UI stuff so it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you display a webview with a HTML form, and need to tell the app once the form is submitted? Or do you just need to send a POST request to some API endpoint?

Comment: just need to send a POST request to some API endpoint

Comment: Oh so in that case a webview may not be what you need. Maybe have a look at Alamofire and use it to send your POST request? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters